# Pipe input redirection to random spot in my new function

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

Sorry for the bad wording of the question, couldn't really think about a decent way to say this.

Problem:
I want a certain sequence to show up, and given is a number, 19 for example.

> > $ echo 19 | seq 1 2 [INPUT FROM PIPE HERE]

So i want the sequence to go from 1, with an increment of 2 till it reaches the input number 19.
And i don't know how to do this, although it's probably very easy, i'm still very new to the shell.

PS: Sorry if this is a duplicate, i couldn't find what i was looking for after 15min searching.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you can pipe parameters into `seq`. But it might be possible to get the output of a command and use it in `seq`.
You might be able to use this though

```
e=$(echo 19) && seq 1 2 "$e"
```

A more straightforward way is:

```
seq 1 2 $(echo 19)
```

This will run a command, `echo 19` in this case, and assigns it to variable `e`. Only if this assignment was successful the next command will run (this is ensured by `&&`). The next program will then use that variable as a parameter via `"$e"`. The double quotation marks are not necessary in this case, but they might be useful in some other cases of this method.